# Преобразование CSV файла в форму обратной связи

Tags: php

Ситуация такая.
Есть сайт по  принтерам.
От заказчика периодически приходит excel (csv) файл, в котором присутствуют столбцы:
производитель принтера -- модель принтера -- картридж
[image: вот пример]
Проблема состоит в следующем.
Вот этот файл надо преобразовать для вывода в форме обратной связи
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Соответственно при выводе формы производители, модели и картриджи не должны повторятся, причем, как видно на скрине, - один картридж может быть использован на нескольких моделях, а у одной модели - несколько картриджей.
Не могу представить себе сам принцип как это реализовать.
Буду рад, если подскажите (в общем) как такое реализуется со стороны php.
Добавляю пример файла .csv

```
Производитель,Модель,Картридж
canon,c1,k1
canon,c1,k2
canon,c2,k3
canon,c3,k3
brother,b1,k4
brother,b1,k5
brother,b2,k6
```

Comment: Приложите содержимое файла `*.csv` текстом, а не картинкой, пожалуйста. И почему в выпадающих списках отображено не то, что в файле `*.csv`?

Comment: Вторая картинка это верстка, по дизайну. А первый скрин - это то, что я пытаюсь сам прикрутить хоть как то к форме.
Интересует, каким образом в php такой файл преобразуют в объект (или массив) для последующей работы с ним, чтоб не получать повторяющихся значений по столбцам

Comment: Вот есть удобная функция [`fgetcsv`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.fgetcsv) для чтения файла. Если нужно переделать в объект, то есть [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode). Нет конкретики в вопросе. Не видно, что вы уже сделали, что не получилось.

Comment: Я дошел до того, что прочитал получаемый файл и вывел его в таблице.
Пытаюсь представить себе алгоритм действий и теряю нить.
1. Получается мне надо записать этот файл в бд (пусть по крону например)
2. При загрузке страницы пользователем - формировать список из производителей
3. При выборе производителя (и далее) слать ajax запрос на получение данных по моделям производителя попутно исключая повторы
4. Составлять новый список из полученных данных...

Я правильно пытаюсь мыслить, или так не делают?